# Access Violation while trying to hook MessageBoxA()

Tags: c++, winapi, runtime-error, access-violation

I recently started C++ (I'm using Visual Studio 22) and am just starting to learn how to use the Windows API. The program is supposed to rewrite `MessageBoxA()`'s memory to jump to `procHook()` when called, but it never does. Instead, it tells me this:

> Unhandled exception at 0xFFFFFFFF94D81290 in hooking.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0xFFFFFFFF94D81290.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>


SIZE_T written = 0;
FARPROC procAddress;
char get[6];


int __stdcall procHook(HWND hWnd, LPCSTR cpt, LPCSTR bdy, UINT type)
{
    
    cpt = "Process hooked";
    bdy = "Child window hooked (Message Box)";
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 0x02);

    std::cout << "Succesfully hooked!\n";

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 0x07);

    std::cout << "Intended caption: " << cpt;
    std::cout << "\nIntended body: " << bdy;

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 0x02);

    std::cout << "\n\nHooked caption: " << cpt;
    std::cout << "\nHooked body: " << bdy << '\n';

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 0x07);

    WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)procAddress, get, sizeof(get), &written);

    return MessageBoxA(NULL, cpt, bdy, type);
}

int main()
{
    std::string caption, body;

    std::cout << "Message caption: ";
    std::cin >> caption;

    std::cout << "Message body: ";
    std::cin >> body;


    HINSTANCE dll = LoadLibraryA("user32.dll");
    SIZE_T read = 0;
    
    procAddress = GetProcAddress(dll, "MessageBoxA");

    ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), procAddress, get, 6, &read);

    void *hookMsg = &procHook;
    char patch[6] = { 0 };
    memcpy_s(patch, 1, "\x68", 1);
    memcpy_s(patch + 1, 4, &hookMsg, 4);
    memcpy_s(patch + 5, 1, "\xC3", 1);

    PDWORD oldProtect{};
    
    WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)procAddress, patch, sizeof(patch), &written);

    MessageBoxA(NULL, caption.c_str(), body.c_str(), MB_OK);
}
```

I assumed the Access Violation was a permission error, so I ran as admin, which didn't work. I also used the `VirtualProtect()` function, which didn't work either.

Here is the code I used:

```cpp
VirtualProtect((LPVOID)procAddress, sizeof(patch), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, oldProtect);
```

I looked into it, and I just can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You're gonna need some `VirtualProtect` calls.  And `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` is not a correct combination (W^X).  You need to make it writeable, make your patch, then change back to execute.

Comment: @badatcpp if you are a beginning in both C++ and the Win32 API, you really have no business tackling an advanced topic like hooking functions. It is simply way outside of your skillset. Use a pre-existing hooking library instead, such as [Microsoft's Detours](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours), let it do all of the hard work for you.

Comment: There's a call to [`FlushInstructionCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-flushinstructioncache) missing, and that's not how you'd hot patch a function anyway (see [Why do Windows functions all begin with a pointless MOV EDI, EDI instruction?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110921-00/?p=9583)).

Answer (score 1):

Just an educated guess: you are building 64-bit exe. But you reserve (and copy) only 4 bytes for the proc address.

Confirming, that same code works in 32-bit build.

For 64-bit, you would need to at least increase the size of your `get` and `patch` by 4 bytes.

Also, I am not familiar with your patching technique. According to http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#xC3, your instruction `"\x68"` is

> 68 PUSH imm16/32 Push Word, Doubleword or Quadword Onto the Stack

Then you copy that 32-bit address, then `"\xC3"`

> C3    RETN                        Return from procedure

<s>I don't really understand what it does</s>, Oh, I think I got it! `RETN` returns from the procedure, by jumping to the address at the top of the stack! Will try to figure this out for x64.

You would likely have to re-code it for 64-bit (the instructions are here: http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html)

**UPDATE:**

I think I got it. You need to up your patch size to 12:

```
const int patch_size = 12;
char get[patch_size];
```

Then, in `main()`:

```
char patch[patch_size] = { 0 };
memcpy_s(patch +  0, 1, "\x48", 1);
memcpy_s(patch +  1, 1, "\xB9", 1);
memcpy_s(patch +  2, 8, &hookMsg, 8);
memcpy_s(patch + 10, 1, "\x51", 1);
memcpy_s(patch + 11, 1, "\xC3", 1);

WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)procAddress, patch, sizeof(patch), &written);
```

And the patch is:

```
00007FFBFE39A010 48 B9 A6 14 52 13 F7 7F 00 00 mov         rcx,7FF7135214A6h  
00007FFBFE39A01A 51                            push        rcx  
00007FFBFE39A01B C3                            ret
```

Comment: could you tell me what to change? on line 63 i changed the code to this
memcpy_s(patch + 1, 8, &hookMsg, 8);
that didnt work though, not sure what to change to fix the issue

Comment: @badatcpp Done. See my updates in the answer ^^

Comment: This is inevitably going to fail, with unpredictable consequences. See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75597878/access-violation-while-trying-to-hook-messageboxa#comment133379355_75597878) for details.